# Unable to create a X509Certificate2 from raw byte array in Xamarin on Android 10

Tags: android, xamarin, x509certificate2

I haven't been able to create a simple X509Certificate2 from the corresponding byte array.
This code shows that the byte array gets recognized as a X509ContentType.Cert, but the next statement throws an exception:

```
var rawCert = Convert.FromBase64String("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");
var type = X509Certificate2.GetCertContentType(rawCert);
var x509 = new X509Certificate2(rawCert);
```

The certificate in the code is a simple custom-made certificate but the same is true for any other certificate that I've tried, even self-signed ones.

The exception thrown by the X509Certificate2 constructor seems to indicate that a wrong type has been detected, contrary to the previous statement outcome:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException
    Message=\`MonoBtlsPkcs12.Import\` failed.
```

Obviously the same code works perfectly fine in any other .Net environment I've tried.

The complete stacktrace is this:

```
at Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsObject.CheckError (System.Boolean ok, System.String callerName) [0x00006] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System/Mono.Btls/MonoBtlsObject.cs:95 
at Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsObject.CheckError (System.Int32 ret, System.String callerName) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System/Mono.Btls/MonoBtlsObject.cs:103 
at Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsPkcs12.Import (System.Byte[] buffer, Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafePasswordHandle password) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System/Mono.Btls/MonoBtlsPkcs12.cs:117 
at Mono.Btls.X509CertificateImplBtls.ImportPkcs12 (System.Byte[] data, Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafePasswordHandle password) [0x0003e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System/Mono.Btls/X509CertificateImplBtls.cs:261 
at Mono.Btls.X509CertificateImplBtls..ctor (System.Byte[] data, Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafePasswordHandle password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/System/Mono.Btls/X509CertificateImplBtls.cs:103
```

Comment: Stactrace please!

Comment: Are you sure the data is correct? The base64 data you have posted is not a pkcs12 file.

Comment: @Robert It's not supposed to be necessarily a pkcs12, the X509Cerificate2 constructor should parse a raw byte array of a DER encoded certificate, with the resulting object not having the private key available, as in any other .NET environment.

Comment: But the base64 data is definitely not a plain certificate, decoding it on https://lapo.it/asn1js/ shows that is has a password protected (encrypted) block inside. So my guess is that it is a PKCS#8 encrypted key with certificate.

Comment: @Robert yes it is, you can see it even with the online tool you referenced.

Answer (score 2):

I digged in a little further and found out the cause of the problem, even though I didn't manage to isolate it and reproduce it.

A library in the App's solution, doing XML signatures, had the NuGet package `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificate` as a dependency, which wasn't necessary because the needed classes are already part of the `System` library of the MonoAndroid framework (the project just needs the `System.Security.Cryptography.Xml` NuGet package, otherwise the `SignedXml` and all the related classes are not available).

Uninstalling the `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificate` NuGet package unexpectedly solved the problem, don't kwnow whay, I need to investigate more, maybe there's some wierd mingling of libraries going on in the final APK package.

Comment: So it was a dependency problem: the library was hiding the X509Certificate functionality of Mono?

Comment: @Robert, yes, that is what I think was happening, but I'm defenetly not expert on mobile development and I didn't think that was even possibile without some previous runtime/compile-time error or warning.