# C# X509Certificate2 can not load certificate from pfx file with password

Tags: c#, linux, x509certificate2

I have a pem file from MongoDB Atlas, which contains both certificate key and private key. It contains single certificate and single key. I have also tried following steps with separate cert and key files, too. In order to connect with MongoDB I generated a pfx file with openssl command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in x509.pem -inkey x509.pem -out x509.pfx
```

By following MongoDB c# connect snippet I'm trying to load pfx into my client app (Which is a Godot Game Engine project) like this:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

public class MongoDBTest : Godot.Node
{
    public override void _Ready()
    {
        try
        {
            var pass = "poiuyt098765";
            var pfx = "temp/x509.pfx";
            var flags = X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet;

            var cert = new X509Certificate2(pfx, pass, flags);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

This snippet fails at certificate2 constructor with Unable to decode certificate. MonoBtlsPkcs12.Import failed.

Here is stack:

```
E 0:00:00.479   void Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsObject.CheckError(Boolean , System.String ): System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Unable to decode certificate. ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: `MonoBtlsPkcs12.Import` failed.
  <C++ Error>   Unhandled exception
  <C++ Source>  :0 @ void Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsObject.CheckError(Boolean , System.String )()
  <Stack Trace> :0 @ void Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsObject.CheckError(Boolean , System.String )()
                :0 @ void Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsObject.CheckError(Int32 , System.String )()
                :0 @ void Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsPkcs12.Import(System.Byte[] , Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafePasswordHandle )()
                :0 @ void Mono.Btls.X509CertificateImplBtls.ImportPkcs12(System.Byte[] , Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafePasswordHandle )()
                :0 @ Mono.Btls.X509CertificateImplBtls..ctor(System.Byte[] , Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafePasswordHandle , System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags )()
                :0 @ --- End of inner exception stack trace ---()
                MongoDBTest.cs:18 @ void MongoDBTest._Ready()()
```

During my google and stack research I came across StorageFlags and since then added 'PersistKey' flag whichs not mentioned in MongoDB reference. I have tried providing bytes to same constructor with same error as above. I tried loading the original PEM file without encryption which makes my project hang without any errors. For example, like `new X509Certificate2("pem/file/path")`. I have tried with X509Certificate2Collection class with X509Store class. Which also produces same error as above at `store.Add(new X509Certificate2(X509Certificate.CreateFrom{Signed/Cert}File("file/path")))` At this point I'm stumped and any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of .NET are you targeting? Have you tried the same with .NET 6 or 7 and not mono?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72966449/unable-to-create-a-x509certificate2-from-raw-byte-array-in-xamarin-on-android-10 works for you

Comment: I already came across above question during my research. In that solution was clearing reference conflict however In my case I'm referencing Cryptography.Certificates not Certificate. Plus, even removing that makes my project fail to compile. As for .Net version. I currently have 6.0 installed.

Comment: I double checked and Godot build is using dotnet cli instead of mono msbuild so It must be using my sdk 6.0.

Comment: Target frame work was net472 so, I tried net48 and net6.0. Project successfully compiled yet during runtime same error. I'm pretty sure the problem is not from Godot side.